python script to parsing each line of a file to excel
I am developing a python script to parsing a each line of a file into excel sheet. currently my script is working to fetch the data into excel in single column with multiple row. my concern is that my script should execute the complete data into rows and columns. as per the input file.

Are you able to share your code?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

My suggestion is to take a look at the CSV package. you can use delimiters to separate rows and columns. let me give you an example: check this picture. You can see that it's using comma as column separator and newline as row separator. So you can create a string like this, paste it in a csv file, and open the csv file with excel.
If your data is structured, like in lists or arrays, you could use csv package or pandas package to help you formulate the csv file. (plz ask gpt for code, looking up the code take a bit of time)
